# AutoComplete using jquery pass value to hidden field

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I hava a autoComplete input field in JSF.

My JSP code

```
<h:form id="setupValue">
  <input type="text" id="department" name="department"/>

<script>
    $("#department").autocomplete("getdept.jsp",{minChars: 4});
</script>
        </h:form>
```

and in getdept.jsp

```
DepartmentMB dept = new DepartmentMB ();
String query = request.getParameter("q");
List<String> dep = dept.getData(query);

Iterator<String> iterator = dep .iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String department = (String)iterator.next();
    String deptName=(String)it.next();
    out.println(deptName);

}
```

How can I send `department` to a hidden field and display `deptName` to inputText field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this ?

```
$("#department").autocomplete({
    source: "getdept.jsp",
    minLength: 4,
    select: function(event, result) { 
        $("#hiddenfield").val(result)
    }
});
```

Obviously getting value is  `$("#hiddenfield").val()`

Comment: I did as  `<script type="text/javascript">
        
        $("#department").autocomplete({
    source: "getdept.jsp",
    minLength: 4,
    select: function(event, result) { 
        $("#hid").val(result)     }
});
       
           </script>` and added a hidden field however autoComplete stopped working though.

Comment: Can you please give me which autocomplete plugin you are using ?

Comment: Baadshah  I am following [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery) example

Comment: So this has to be added as Javascript? not as Jquery?

Comment: No.you are doing in a right way.Please let me check the example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26853/discussion-between-baadshah-and-polppan)